# How may a largest fixed-point be defined in second order logic?

Tags: lo.logic

Adapting from Anil Gupta and & Nuel Belnap, *Revision theory of truth*, MIT 1993, p. 194, in the context of a second order logic, where $A(x.G)$ is a formula where $G$ only occurs positively, a fixed point

$$\forall x(Gx\leftrightarrow A(x,G))$$

may be isolated. One may also show

$$\forall x(Gx\leftrightarrow\forall H[\forall x(Hx\leftrightarrow A(x,H))\rightarrow Hx])$$

I understand how these together define a least fixed point of $A(x,G)$.

How may one define a largest fixed point of $A(x,G)$ in the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as the least fixed point is the intersection of all the sets $H$ such that $\forall x\,(A(x,H)\to H(x))$, so (dually) the greatest fixed point is the union of all the sets $K$ such that $\forall x\,(K(x)\to A(x,K))$.

Alternatively, one can use duality to obtain the greatest fixed point of $A(x,G)$ as the complement of the least fixed point of $\neg A(x,\neg G)$.

Comment: As in $$Gx\leftrightarrow\exists H(\forall x(Hx\rightarrow A(x,H))\wedge Hx)$$?

Comment: Isn't the greatest fixed point just the whole structure in question?

Comment: @NoahSchweber No, because the whole structure might not be fixed. A good example would be the Cantor-Bendixson derivative, as a monotone map from closed subsets (of some decent ambient space) to closed subsets. Its greatest fixed point is the perfect piece in the Cantor-Bendixson decomposition of the ambient space into countable + perfect.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal That looks correct to me (but it's 11 p.m. here).

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see that the truth of the R.S. $$\exists H(\forall x(Hx\rightarrow A(x,H))\wedge Hx)$$ entails $$(Gx\rightarrow A(x,G))\wedge Gx$$. But I do not see that $$Gx$$ (or $$(Gx\rightarrow A(x,G))\wedge Gx$$) entails the R.S.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Excuse me, I see how $$(Gx\rightarrow A(x,G))\wedge Gx$$ entails the  R.S. 

Is $$((Gx\rightarrow A(x,G))\wedge Gx)\leftrightarrow\exists H(\forall x(Hx\rightarrow A(x,H))\wedge Hx)$$ the desired fixed point?

Comment: I thought we should also get $$(Gx\leftrightarrow A(x,G))$$.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Now that I'm awake, the formulation in your first comment still looks correct (though I'd prefer not to have the same variable free at some occurrences & bound at others). In particular, the $G$ that it defines is a fixed point, i.e., it does what you asked about in your most recent comment.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks! Now I see it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass For the possible benefit of others, and for my own notes. 

Suppose DF: $$Gx\leftrightarrow\exists H(\forall y(Hy\rightarrow A(y,H))\wedge Hx)$$

Comment: Logical consequence (1) of DF:

$$A(x,H)\rightarrow(Gx\leftrightarrow Hx)$$

Comment: Logical consequence (2) of DF:

$$Hx\rightarrow(Gx\leftrightarrow A(x,H))$$

Comment: Consequence (3):

$$\forall x(Hx\wedge A(x,H))\rightarrow(\forall x(Gx\leftrightarrow Hx)\wedge\forall x (Gx\leftrightarrow A(x,H)))$$

Comment: $$\forall x((Hx\rightarrow A(x,H))\wedge Hx)\rightarrow((Hx\wedge A(x,H))$$

Comment: $$\exists H(\forall x((Hx\rightarrow A(x,H))\wedge Hx))\rightarrow(\forall x(Gx\leftrightarrow A(x,G)))$$

Comment: So if there is a fixed point of A(x,H) then G is such a fixed point.